# Indexing on DateTime and VARCHAR fields in SQL Server 2000, which one is more effectient?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, optimization, indexing, varchar

We have a **CallLog** table in [Microsoft SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950404.aspx). The table contains **CallEndTime** field whose type is [`DATETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx), and it's an index column.

We usually delete free-charge calls and generate monthly fee statistics report and [call detail record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record) report, all the SQLs use `CallEndTime` as query condition in [`WHERE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260674%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) clause. Due to a lot of records exist in CallLog table, the queries are slow, so we want to optimize it starting from indexing.

#### Question

Will it more effictient if query upon an extra indexed [`VARCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) column **CallEndDate** ?
Such as

```
-- DATETIME based query
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CallLog WHERE CallEndTime BETWEEN '2011-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-06-30 23:59:59'

-- VARCHAR based queries
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CallLog WHERE CallEndDate BETWEEN '2011-06-01' AND '2011-06-30'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CallLog WHERE CallEndDate LIKE '2011-06%'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CallLog WHERE CallEndMonth = '2011-06'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be the datetime.  Dates are essentially stored as a number in the database so it is relatively quick to see if the value is between two numbers.

If I were you, I'd consider splitting the data over multiple tables (by month, year of whatever) and creating a view to combine the data from all those tables.  That way, any functionality which needs to entire data set can use the view and anything which only needs a months worth of data can access the specific table which will be a lot quicker as it will contain much less data.

Comment: Will it quicker than the last VARCHAR(7) based query or VARCHAR(4) based query?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think comparing `DateTime` is much faster than `LIKE` operator.
2. I agree with DoctorMick on Spliting your DateTime as persisted columns Year, Month, Day
3. for your query which selects `COUNT(*)`, check if in the `execution plan` there is a `Table LookUp` node. if so, this might be because your  CallEndTime  column is nullable. because you said that you have a [nonclustered] index on CallEndTime column. if you make your column NOT NULL and rebuild that index, counting it would be a `INDEX SCAN` which is not so slow.and I think you will get much faster results.